# &lt; converted to < when parsing with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-escape-characters

I'm using beautiful soup to parse a string containing `&lt;br>`, which beautiful soup is interpreting as `<br>`.

Is there a way I can get beautiful soup to stop doing this, so that `&lt;br>` is left untouched and treated as a plain string, while `<br>` is parsed normally?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `formatter="html"` to let the interpreter know about it as raw html. Basically the if you play around with the `formatter` option you can get what you are expecting. 
The [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters) has details about it.

Comment: I can't immediately see how to apply this. Using `soup.prettify(formatter="html")` still gives me `<br>`, and I don't use the encode or decode functions arewhere in my code.

Comment: It seems like the formatter option is set only for the encode, decode and prettify functions, which are all applied to an already-parsed document. The behaviour I want to stop is happening during the parsing, so this is too late. My current workaround is to replace `&lt;` with other characters, and reverse the replacement once I'm through using beautiful soup.